# Twig loop in array stucked

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, twig

How to loop in array like this in twig.

**var_dump($array) , array was formed by fetchAll() (PDO)**

```
array (size=3)
            0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'comment' => string 'Labas' (length=5)
      0 => string 'Labas' (length=5)
      'user_name' => string 'Qler' (length=4)
      1 => string 'Qler' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'comment' => string 'asdg' (length=4)
      0 => string 'asdg' (length=4)
      'user_name' => string 'Qler' (length=4)
      1 => string 'Qler' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'comment' => string 'adf' (length=3)
      0 => string 'adf' (length=3)
      'user_name' => string 'Qler' (length=4)
      1 => string 'Qler' (length=4)
```

I like to have something like this to display comment: username;

Also accept advices for simplify this array in PHP (i am using PDO).

Answer (score 1):

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Downvoted for doing no research on your own.

Quote:
Loop over each item in a sequence. For example, to display a list of users provided in a variable called users:

```
<h1>Members</h1>
<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You should also switch to either using only associative or only indexed fetch mode. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php